# Add cluster's legend in ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have ggplot heatmap with rows clustered by kmeans (15 clusters).

```
MotifPresence.kmeans = kmeans(MotifPresence, 15)
class.promoter = MotifPresence.kmeans$cluster
MotifPresence.kmeans.ordered = MotifPresence[order(class.promoter), MPbindist.hclust$order]
x=colnames(MotifPresence)[MPbindist.hclust$order]
y=rownames(MotifPresence)
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)

data$Z <- as.vector(t((MotifPresence.kmeans.ordered)))

ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, z= Z)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Z)) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
scale_fill_gradient(name = "Score", low = "white", high = "darkgreen") +
ylab("") +xlab("")
```

How can I add some marks to this heatmap to show boundaries between this clusters? Probably horizontal lines or additional column with different colours for each cluster?

[image: heatmap with clusters]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
class.size = MotifPresence.kmeans$size
levels = cumsum(class.size)+0.5
my.lines<-data.frame(x=c(.5), y=c(levels), 
                 xend=c(17.5), yend=c(levels))
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, z= Z)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Z)) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
scale_fill_gradient(name = "Score", low = "white", high = "darkgreen") +
ylab("") +xlab("") + 
geom_segment(data=my.lines, aes(x,y,xend=xend, yend=yend), size=0.1, inherit.aes=F)
```

[image]